# Image file was not found for custom attribute

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I am using magento 1.9.1

I have added media attribute name 'offer_image' in images.

I have also set in attribute set and added image to this attribute in product page.

When I try to get this attribute image on frontent it show error

"Image file was not found"

I am using this code to get image

```
$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'offer_image')->resize(50);
```

This code work fine if I use thumbnail or small_image.

How should I get custom attribute image, what is wrong with code.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having the same problem right now, and unable to find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try to load a product first (looks like you're taking it from a collection):

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId());
$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'offer_image')->resize(50);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php  if ($_product->getOfferImage() && ($_product->getOfferImage() != 'no_selection')):?>
    <img src="<?php echo $_product->getOfferImage();?>">
<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: You should add more details in your answer : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: just add condition and solving it